# Static text in parallax scroll

Tags: text, parallax

I'm working on my portfolio website and wanted to use parallax-scrolling but only to change the main text like on this website I found.

Here is the [link](http://www.stinkdigital.com/).

Can anyone please tell me how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with a basic tutorial for the technique.

Here is a description:

As you scroll, the background images translate slower than the content in the foreground, creating the illusion of 3D depth.